# Create dropdownlist and two textbox each time when click button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework

I am trying on every button click to add a drop-down list (filled from a database using EF) and two textboxes dynamically,
and after that store tha value from list and textbox into the database.

How can I do that using asp.nrt(vb) and EF?

Comment: SO is not designed for code writing service. Ask the question you face during implement instead of asking the community to do your homework.

Comment: yes ur right,thank for ur advice

Answer (score 0):

First you will want to set up a Panel on the Client side to hold your new Textbox, and dropdownlists like below:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlButton" runat="server" Width="100%"/>
```

Then you will want to have a event set up like this for your button click.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim tb As New TextBox
        tb.ID = "TextBox1"
        Dim ddl As New DropDownList
        ddl.ID = "DropDownList1"
        ddl.DataSource = 'your data source from the Database'
        pnlButton.Controls.Add(tb)
        pnlButton.Controls.Add(ddl)
    End Sub
```

This should get you started on atleast creating the controls dynamically.